# Local User Credential Check in windows 2012 server

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, credentials, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-4.0

I am trying to validate the local user credential using the below code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$DS = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext('machine',$ComputerName)
$status=$DS.ValidateCredentials($UserName, $Password)
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Exception calling "ValidateCredentials" with "2" argument(s): "The specified network name is no longer available.
"
At line:1 char:1
+ $ds.ValidateCredentials('User','Password')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PrincipalOperationException
```

Please help me to fix this out.

Thanks in advance

Note: I am not getting this error in all the machine. Out of 87 machines i am getting this error in 12 machines alone.

Comment: on the 12 computers on which it is not working on are you able to ping the name being provided by `$ComputerName`?

Comment: yes, the servers are pinging. These commands are executed within the server itself

Comment: Please see [this question for other issues with your code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911042/powershell-local-credential-verification)

Comment: Hi. i tried it earlier. it didn't help. the code is giving the same error as stated above

Answer (score 0):

Starting 'server' service fixed the issue